# Rational numbers from irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory

Can any real function of irrational numbers  be rational ? If possible, please give examples. Special case  $ e^ {\pi i } = -1 $ seems to restrict solutions entirely to complex numbers. The question is right now vague as I do not know how to  exclude "obviously  derived " examples.

Comment: Maybe more interesting to try to find a surjection $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: On the opposite, can you find a continuous function that never maps an irrational to a rational, other than a rational fraction ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $f(x)=|x|$?

Comment: @Wojowu: all piecewise functional inverses of rational fractions with rational coefficients never map an irrational to a rational. $|x|$ is such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A well-known example.

Is $m:=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ rational?  If yes, that is your answer.

If no, then $m^\sqrt{2}$ is your answer: $m$ and $\sqrt{2}$ are irrational, but
$$
m^\sqrt{2} = \left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{2}
=\sqrt{2}^{(\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2})} = \sqrt{2}^2 = 2
$$
is rational.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223725/) generalizes this example.

Answer (score 10):

Sure. Choose any constant function $f : \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$, for example

$$f(x) = 1 \quad\text{ for all } x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$$

If this answer seems flippant, you may want to sharpen the question.

Comment: For kicks, define it as conways base 13 function everywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

The cosine of $\pi$ is -1, a rational number.

Answer (score 5):

You can construct required function from any real function, rounding the result to finite number of decimals.

Answer (score 4):

What about $f(x)=x^2$? One has $f(\sqrt2)=2$.

Comment: should work for any, not only for square roots ...

Comment: @oops, algebraic of course.

Comment: More generally, all algebraic numbers evaluate to $0$ for some polynomial function.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, what you say is ambiguous (in English!). Better to say, “Every algebraic number evaluates to $0$ for some polynomial function”.

Comment: @Lubin: I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand your question, since it seems to be insufficiently quantified. Do you mean, “Is there a function that takes every irrational number to a rational?”? Or do you mean, “Given an irrational number, is there a function that takes it to a rational image?”? Your example seems to support the second interpretation, in which case I’d suggest the function $f(x)=x/a$, if your given irrational number is $a$.

And you didn’t say what kind of function you were allowing. Any continuous function? Analytic? I can suggest all manner of discontinuous functions that take irrationals to rationals, beyond of course the ultimate in continuity, the constant functions.

Comment: I meant a situation about any  function of rationals  mapped  from independent irrational variable numbers,

Answer (score 0):

According to a famous theorem about trascendental numbers for all $\alpha$ real algebraic with $1\ne\alpha\ne0$ the number $\ln \alpha$ is trascendental. Consider the function $f(x)=e^x$ which is a bijection of $\mathbb R$ onto $]0,\infty[$; take now un $r\in$ $\mathbb Q^+ $, for instance $r=7$; there exists x such that $f(x)=7$ but $f(x)=e^x=7\iff x=\ln 7$ hence $x$ is a trascendental number whose image by $f$ is rational.

You have this way infinitely many rational $r$ such that if $x=\ln r$ then $f(x)=r$ where x is irrational (it is trascendental indeed).

Comment: Is the theorem that you mention a particular case of the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)?

Answer (score 0):

Several.

`f(x) = x - x = 0`

`f(x) = x / x = 1, for x in R - {0}`

`f(x) = round(x, 5)`, where round() rounds a number to the specified quantity of decimal places.

The [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

```
f(x) = 
    1 if x in Q,
    0 if x not in Q
```

`f(x) =`The average of the first 10^6 digits of x (in base 10).

And so on...