# Is there an irrational number $a$ such that $a^a$ is rational?

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers

It can be proved that there are two irrational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^b$ is rational (see [Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational)) and that for each irrational number $c$ there exists another irrational number $d$ such that $c^d$ is rational (see [For each irrational number b, does there exist an irrational number a such that a^b is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223725/for-each-irrational-number-b-does-there-exist-an-irrational-number-a-such-t)).

My question is: Is there an irrational number $a$ such that $a^a$ is rational (and how could you prove that)?

Comment: $a^a=x$ has at least one real solution $a$ for each positive rational $x$, so all we need is to prove that there exists an $x$ such that $a$ must be irrational... (I suggest $x=2$ as a worthy candidate...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the unique (positive) solution $a$ to $x^x = 2$. If $a$ were rational, say, $a = \frac{p}{q}$, $p$ and $q$ are positive integers such that $\gcd(p, q) = 1$, we would have $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{p / q} = 2 ,$$ and rearranging gives
$$p^p = q^p 2^q .$$
Since there is no integer $n$ such that $n^n = 2$, we must have $q > 1$ and hence $2 \mid p^p$. Because $2$ is prime, we have $2 \mid p$. So, $2$ occurs an even number of times the prime factorization of $p^p$ and likewise of $q^p$. Since $p^p = q^p 2^q$, we must have $2 \mid q$, but now $2 \mid p, q$, and this contradicts $\gcd(p, q) = 1$. Thus, $a$ is irrational but $a^a$ is rational (in fact, an integer).

Answer (score 20):

By continuity of the function $x^x$, there is an $a$ such that

$$a^a=2.$$

This number is irrational. Otherwise, let $a$ be the irreducible fraction $p/q$ and

$$\left(\frac pq\right)^{p/q}=2,$$
is equivalent to
$$p^p=2^qq^p,$$

which implies that $p$ is even and $q$ is even, a contradiction.

---

By the way, as

$$\ln(a^a)=a\ln(a)=\ln(a)e^{\ln(a)},$$

we have

$$\color{green}{a=e^{W(\ln(2))}}$$

where $W$ is the Lambert function.

Comment: (Independently of @abiessu)

Comment: I wholly approve :-)

Answer (score 6):

If $a^a=2$, then $a$ is irrational: If $a=p/q$, then $(p/q)^p=2^q$ is an integer, so $p/q$ is an integer.