# Prove or disprove: For every irrational number x, there exists an irrational number y such that x^y is a rational number

Tags: irrational-numbers, formal-proofs

I just thought of this statement on a bus on my way back from my Math class. I gave  it a lot of thought, but we have not covered how to prove nested quantifier statements, and I have no clue how to approach this. I asked my professor and she said she didn't know how to approach this problem right away either. But this is keeping me up at night for some reason. I don't even know if this statement is true or false. My intuition says it is false, but then again I am unable to find a counterexample of x and prove that for all irrational exponents, the answer is never rational.
If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be really really appreciated!

Comment: This is Proposition 1 of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1223725/87023 . Here's a hint: you don't have to assume that $x$ is irrational!

Comment: Let $x>0, x\ne 1$; show first that if $r,s$ are nonzero fractions $2^r \ne 3^s$ and then show that implies that $\log_x 2, \log_x 3$ cannot be both rational and conclude

Answer (score 3):

This raises the matter of defining $x^y$ for $x<0$ and $y$ not an integer. For $x\in(0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$, you can use a trick like the following. Observe that $\log_23$ is irrational: in fact, $2^m\ne 3^n$ for any $n\ne0$. Then, either $\log_x2$ is rational or it isn't. If it is rational, then $\log_x2\cdot \log_23=\log_x3$ is irrational.